# Populate menu items in different <div>

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to populate four menu items in Silverstripe. I have managed to populate the first two menu items with SS using li class="area{$Pos}" in one div. However, the third and fourth menu items are in different div and class from the first two. I've been searching but not sure how to use SS to populate the third and fourth menus items in different div(/second div> and class? Sorry I'm new to it, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
<div id="top">
<ul class="sf-menu">
     <% control Menu(1) %>
       <li id="area{$Pos}">
        <a href="#a">$MenuTitle</a>
           <% if Children %>
                 <ul><% control Children %>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#aa">$MenuTitle</a>

                         <% if Children %>
                            <ul>
                            <% control Children %>
                                 <li>
                                 <a href="#aa">$MenuImg.SetSize(20,20) $MenuTitle</a>
                                  </li>
                            <% end_control %>
                            </ul>
                        <% end_if %>
                       </li>
                   <% end_control %>

                </ul><% end_if %>

          </li>
         <% end_control %>

</ul>
</div>

<div id="test" >
<ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical">
      <li id="area3">
      <a href="#a">Area 3</a>
      </li>

      <li id="area4">
      <a href="#">Area 4</a>
        <ul class="show_left">
          <li>
           <a href="#">Store one</a>

          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">Store Two</a>

          </li>

       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're already using the $Pos Control ([see the docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/built-in-page-controls#pos-totalitems)) in your code, you can also use it inside an 'if' block.
this should do the trick (untested):

**BEWARE** this snippet doesn't work as expected. see the **UPDATE** below

```
<% control Menu(1) %>
<% if Pos == 1 || Pos == 2 %>
<div>render items 1 and 2 here</div>
<% end_if %>
<% end_control %>

<% control Menu(1) %>
<% if Pos == 3 || Pos == 4 %>
<div>render items 3 and 4 here</div>
<% end_if %>
<% end_control %>
```

just note that `<% if Pos < 3 %>` syntax isn't supported.
for a cleaner way to do the same thing, refer to [this snippet](http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2009/manipulating-every-nth-item-in-a-control-loop/) on ssbits.

**UPDATE**

unfortunately, silverstripe doesn't seem to support more complex conditions as above either.
this one is supported ([as in the docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/advanced-templates#if-blocks)):

```
<% if MyBoolean || MyOtherBoolean %>
```

whereas this one isn't:

```
<% if MyInteger == 1 || MyInteger == 2 %>
```

so, the best solution seems to be the second one i pointed you too (the snippet on ssbits above).
in your case, this could read as follows:

add functions to the 'Page' class you're using to check the current position:

```
public function InFirstDiv() {
  return ($this->iteratorPos == 1 || $this->iteratorPos == 2);
}
public function InSecondDiv() {
  return ($this->iteratorPos == 3 || $this->iteratorPos == 4);
}
```

then, call them in your template:

```
<% control Menu(1) %>
<% if InFirstDiv %>
<div>render items 1 and 2 here</div>
<% end_if %>
<% end_control %>

<% control Menu(1) %>
<% if InSecondDiv %>
<div>render items 3 and 4 here</div>
<% end_if %>
<% end_control %>
```

doesn't look very smart - but should work this time :)

Comment: Hi Schellmax, Thanks very much (yet again) to help me! I tried your suggestion, and I got an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'" Even when I tried the first two Pos, <% if Pos == 1 || Pos == 2 %> it shows the same error. Is it because the double if conditions? Or is it related to the <% if Pos < 3 %> syntax you mentioned, I'm a bit lost on that matter too. Is it possible for you to explain it a bit more for me? Thanks very very much!

Comment: i should really have tested my code before posting it here, sorry for that. see my update above.

Comment: Hi Schellmax, thanks very much for your kind reply. Sorry I was away so didn't follow it up, the project has been postponed, but I will let you know later on if I get back to it and make it work again. Thanks so much for all your great help, I really appreciated!! All the best, S:)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you do NOT want to structure this on the position, because if you want to change it to 1-3 pages in the first and 4-5 in the second div, you'd need to change the underlying template.

Instead I would create 2 pages (probably redirect pages - you can select that in the CMS) under which you'd add the pages you want to display in your template. So you would have something like this in the CMS:

- Redirect page /foo

  - Page1
  - Page2
- Redirect page /bar

  - Page3
  - Page4

In your template you could then use `<% control ChildrenOf(foo) %>` (or `bar`) to access the pages of your two different regions.

NOTE: If you run into template errors, be sure to put your page into development mode and append `?showtemplate=1` to your URL. This will show you the compiled template file where you can then find the actual error.

PS: Obviously you'll need to change your template if you change the URLs, but that's something I try to avoid on live projects (broken external links,...), while new menu entries are pretty common.

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks very much for your reply. My menu structure is that Menu item 1 and 2 are in one div, and Menu item 3 and 4 are in second div with a different class. All four menus are on the same level in Silverstripe. How can I tell SS to populate second <div id="test"> <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical"> area with Menu item 3 and 4 only? Hope that makes sense.

Thank you very much for your help.
S:)

Comment: Note on template debugging added and I still don't like the position based approach, but that's up to you...

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks very much for your replies. Sorry I was away so didn't follow it up, and the project got postponed. But I will let you know how I go as soon as I go back to the project. Anyhow, thanks very much for your kind help. S:)